# How to loop the value of URL query string within the get_content in PHP and echo respective data?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to parse some data from an API which has the result in json format.
I am successfully able to do it for one parameter as shown in the code below which outputs some data as I expect.

`$json = get_content('site.tld/api.php?country=0');
$decode = json_decode($json);
echo "RUSSIA: ".$decode->kt;`

I want to change the value of the country QueryString in get_content with an array (0,1,2,5,10,20 etc) which should correspondingly change the values in my echo output. Basically another set of array.
Example: 0 should correspond to RUSSIA (which is the default case). 1 to USA, 2 to Brazil, 5 to Kazakhstan and so on.

I can only think of repeating the above code for every value of country like below:

`$json = get_content('site.tld/api.php?country=0');
$decode = json_decode($json);
echo "RUSSIA: ".$decode->kt;`

`$json = get_content('site.tld/api.php?country=1');
$decode = json_decode($json);
echo "USA: ".$decode->kt;`

`$json = get_content('site.tld/api.php?country=2');
$decode = json_decode($json);
echo "Brazil: ".$decode->kt;`

But there are approximately 50+ parameters and I think it's a very bad code but it does work. How can I do it efficiently?

Thank you.

Comment: What about looping over your array

Comment: How do you know which number is which country?

Comment: @LewisBlundell I know this data. That's why I've given example as above.

Comment: What I meant was you would be able to do a loop but we need to know how the data is going to be laid out.  We can’t match up the countries to the numbers unless we know how it is structured. You will need to provide us with more information of the data or how do we know if England is 3 or 12 or 25?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach()` loop and get the `key`/`value` pairs of your array and use them to dynamically display the data.

```
$countries =  array(0 => 'Russia', 1 => 'USA', 2 => 'Brazil', 5 => 'Kazakhstan', /*and so on....*/); 
// key is set in array and it equals value ex. 0 => "Russia"
```

or maybe

```
$countries =  array('Russia', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Kazakhstan', /*and so on....*/);
// key is not defined, yet exists and iterates starting at 0 then increments by 1 until the last key/value is reached inside the array
```

`forloop($array as $key => $value){ //iterate through each key/value pair and collect data }`

```
$stmt = null; //create an empty variable to hold your content

// loop through the array and get the key/value --> $code/$country pairs
foreach($countries as $code => $country){
    $json = get_content('site.tld/api.php?country='.$code); // Code is the key
    $decode = json_decode($json);
    $stmt .= $country.": ".$decode->kt."<br>"; // $country is the value
}

<?=$stmt?> <--or--> <?php echo $stmt; ?> // echo out result
```